# Is there a way I can programmatically download the latest version of Craft?

Tags: setup, install

If you have a base install script that you use to quickly turn out a new base install for Craft, it would be very useful for that script to be able to download the latest version of Craft when doing it’s new site setup logic.

What’s the best way to do that?

Comment: Note: If said base install script were made publicly available (e.g. https://github.com/mattstauffer/makeItCraft/ ), be sure to prompt the user for license acceptance so that it doesn't become a method of someone theoretically bypassing accepting the user agreement.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**In Craft 3:**

You can download the latest Craft 3 release in zip or .tar.gz format by going to:

```
https://craftcms.com/latest.zip
https://craftcms.com/latest.tar.gz
```

Or since Craft 3 is [Composer](https://getcomposer.org) based, you can modify your `composer.json`'s `craftcms/cms` line to install the specific version you're looking for.

**In Craft 2:**

You can get the latest Craft 2 version in either zip or tar.gz format by going to:

```
https://craftcms.com/latest-v2.zip
https://craftcms.com/latest-v2.tar.gz
```

Comment: cool! didn't know that flag was there, thought you wanted to block commandline downloads when you added that js tickbox! thanks!