# Is it possible to get the md5 hash of Craft's latest version from the download server?

Tags: install, setup

It is possible to [programmatically download the latest version of craft](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/225/is-there-a-way-i-can-programmatically-download-the-latest-version-of-craft/226#226). But is it also possible to get this file's md5 sum directly from the server?

I'm thinking about something like this:

```
http://buildwithcraft.com/latest.hash
```

I am asking this because I'm currently writing a [Salt](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/) formula to install Craft. I intend to use [salt.states.files.managed](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.managed), which is capable of downloading a file only if it has a different md5 sum than an already downloaded version of the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently not, but that's not a bad idea and probably worth adding to https://feedback.buildwithcraft.com.

During an auto-update, the file name of the patch file that is downloaded happens to be the MD5 sum of the file so the Craft client can verify the integrity of the downloaded file, but there isn't a mechanism like that in place currently for full Craft downloads.